# Vertical menu on the left of the screen Android

Tags: android, menu

i wanna create a Menu which come from the left of the screen, classics menu came from the bottom of the screen `onclick` on Menu button, is there a way to make it vertical and come from the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should intercept the button menu and display your custom view.
Probably [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidMenusMyWay.aspx) is a good starting point.

[EDIT]

A new approach for a vertical menu on the left of the screen is to create a "Fly-in-App" menu as decribed from Cyril Mottier in [his blog](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=658). 
To achieve something like that you can use [android-menudrawer library](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer)

Comment: how could i make my custom view slippery like the default menu?

Comment: Writing a simple slide from left animation :) there a lot of examples, just take a look on google.

Answer (score 1):

There's a custom SlidingDrawer by pskink that you can use.  It lets you position your menu at the top, left, right, or bottom of the screen.